# Transaction in local mempool not broadcasted further

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, mempool, lightning-network-daemon

I created a bitcoin transaction from `lnd` (`lncli sendcoins`), and it seems to be created successfully and I can see it in my local `bitcoind` mempool:

```
bitcoin-cli getmempoolentry abdctxid {
 "vsize": 130,
 "weight": 520,
 "time": 1692559301,
 "height": 804102,
 "descendantcount": 1,
 "descendantsize": 130,
 "ancestorcount": 1,
 "ancestorsize": 130,
 "wtxid": "bcdetxid",
 "fees": {
   "base": 0.00000786,
   "modified": 0.00000786,
   "ancestor": 0.00000786,
   "descendant": 0.00000786
 },
 "depends": [
 ],
 "spentby": [
 ],
 "bip125-replaceable": false,
 "unbroadcast": false
}
```

It is however not being broadcasted further, the receiver did not see the transaction, and it is not visible in various online explorers.

Using Bitcoin Core v23.0.0. The only non-default setting in my config is `minrelaytxfee=0.00000011 blockmintxfee=0.00000011 maxmempool=300`.

As far as I know this is the first time in years it happened to my node. What could be the reason for the transaction being stuck in my local mempool and is there a way to force-rebroadcast it further?

Comment: It's hard to tell with so little information. Anything else uncommon? Do you have peers at all (`getpeerinfo`)? Any high CPU usage from the `bitcoind` process? Anything peculiar in the `debug.log`? Have you tried upgrading you `bitcoind` to the latest (25.0) version or at least the patched (23.2) version?

Comment: Thanks for directions! `getpeerinfo` shows ~50 peers, no suspiciously high CPU usage, upgrading to `23.2` does not help. Grepping `debug.log` for the txid or "mempool" or "err" does not show anything interesting. Really not sure what else to check...

Comment: Out of all the things, restarting `lnd` helped! Maybe there is some logic on the wallet side that forced transaction to be rebroadcasted, but now it is visible to other nodes as well. Still super weird that this happened though.